# Как вставить html символ в canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Пробовал разные варианты, ни один не подходит

```js
function drawText(ctx, text, x, y) {
  ctx.font = '28px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = "#333333";
    ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth +'px';
canvas.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight +'px';
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * 2;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * 2;

// напрямую символом × работает, но нужно кодом
drawText(ctx, "Close: × U+000D7 &#xd7; &#215; &times; \00D7", 20, 60);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function drawText(ctx, text, x, y) {
  ctx.font = '28px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = "#333333";
    ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth +'px';
canvas.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight +'px';
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * 2;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * 2;

// напрямую символом × работает, но нужно кодом
//drawText(ctx, "Close: × U+000D7 &#xd7; &#215; &times; \00D7", 20, 60);
drawText(ctx, "Close: \u00D7", 20, 60);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```