# Как в canvas при наведении на блок поменять курсор мыши?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Аналогичное в css `cursor: pointer;`

```js
function drawBar(ctx, x, y, w, h, color = '#000', radius = 0) {
  ctx.save();
  if (radius > 0) {
    ctx.arc(x, y, w, h, radius * Math.PI);
  }
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.restore();
}
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth +'px';
canvas.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight +'px';
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * 2;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * 2;

drawBar(ctx, 40, 40, 160, 60, '#090', 5);
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367726

Comment: Странно, даже уведомления небыло об ответе, спасибо, а то я уже отложил задачу. Поставил галочку

Comment: Придумал что то типа такого `canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';` и через координаты `e.offsetX` высчитать, только не пойму какие условия должны быть проставлены в позиционировании

Comment: Ваш вопрос можно свести к тому как определить, что курсор над блоком, а по этой тематике полно ответов. Есть через isPointInPath() или через getImageData() сравнивать с цветом. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath, например